# Is there a way in a Bazel macro to get the package that called it?

Tags: bazel

In a bazel macro I want to get the package name that called it. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

`native.package_name()` will return the current package name from within a macro, or just `package_name()` from within a BUILD file.

https://bazel.build/rules/lib/native#package_name